# Laravel "load" relations function of Model produces "unprepared" statement in SQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, prepared-statement

I'm experiencing issue in Laravel (v7.28) models with usage of `load` function.
It executes the SQL query without params ("?") but with the raw values.

Instead of:

```
SELECT * from relation_table where relation_table.model_id IN (?)
```

It executes:

```
SELECT * from relation_table where relation_table.model_id IN (123)
```

In case if I have a lot of SQL queries it produces unprepared SQL statements and I reach the limit with the SQL error:
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1461 Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements`

Also, I detected that `refresh` function calls the same `load` function inside so this issue will be relevant for this function as well.

Is it possible to avoid or fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you may have to increase the max_prepared_stmt_count in your mysql server, ou should add it in /etc/my.cnf on this way:

```
[mysqld]
max_prepared_stmt_count = 50000
```

Comment: Yes, we already set it to 16382 but it's not the best way to I believe, as we hide the problem, not resolve it.